# Update of an array that is sent from a chat server to chat clients

Tags: java, arraylist, server, chat

I've found a code of a chat server that I have a short question to. It is about the following excerpt:

**clientOutputStreams.add(writer)**;

Obviously this array of strings should be sent to the chat clients, but I don't get how the array ever gets updated - i.e. how strings sent to the server from particular chat clients are accumualated in the array and then sent back to all chat clients. Do you? Would appreciate you help.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


public class VerySimpleChatServer {
ArrayList clientOutputStreams;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    BufferedReader reader;
    Socket sock;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSOcket) {
        try {
            sock = clientSOcket;
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);

        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    public void run() {
        String message;
        try {
            while ((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("read " + message);
                tellEveryone(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new VerySimpleChatServer().go();
}

public void go() {
    clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList();
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while(true) {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept();
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientOutputStreams.add(writer);

            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
            t.start();
            System.out.println("got a connection");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
}

public void tellEveryone(String message) {
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
            writer.println(message);
            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: clientOutputStreams is not an array of *strings*, but an array of *streams* => that is, the "pipes" to the clients.

Comment: does it mean that if there are 10 clients in total, the size of the clientOutputStream is 10?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Each time a client connection is accepted, this list is grown. As stated in below answers, each time a string is written on console, it's broadcasted to the clients, one string at a time.

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously this array of strings should be sent to the chat clients,

It's not an array of strings.  It's an array of PrintWriters as you can see from the following lines:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
clientOutputStreams.add(writer);
```

> but I don't get how the array ever gets updated - i.e. how strings sent to the server from particular chat clients are accumualated in the array and then sent back to all chat clients. Do you?

Looks like the strings are sent to the chat clients through the function

```
public void tellEveryone(String message)
```

This function loops through each of the PrintWriters and writes the passed string `message` to each `PrintWriter`.  I would guess this is how each client sees the messages.

Comment: So the size of the array clientOutputStreams is the amount of the clients connected to the server - is it right? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`clientOutputStreams` isn't an array of strings. It's a list of [Writer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) which is used in order to send a message to all connected clients. When ever a client sends a message to the server, the server sends the message (method: `tellEveryone`) to every client (every writer in the list). The `ClientHandler` class is used to read all incoming messages from client. Hope that helps you understand the code a little bit better.